# What software solutions exist to live stream video over a LAN?

Tags: streaming, youtube, video-streaming

A school is streaming the morning announcements through a You Tube live stream. The [result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J9KgsLNB0Q) is great when it works. Frequently the stream is lost for reasons outside of our control (e.g. upstream or downstream internet connection, Youtube latency, or something else)

The announcements need to be broadcast to about 60 classrooms (60 computers) and do not really need to be archived on YouTube. What other solutions can we consider?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

A [DLNA Server](http://www.howtogeek.com/215400/how-to-turn-your-computer-into-a-dlna-media-server/) to store the content and [Chromecast](https://www.google.com/intl/en_en/chromecast/tv/#?discover) on the receiver screens can be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done as simple as saving the morning announcement as a video file, then letting clients use HTTP to play it off a local web server.

If you really want live streaming, I believe you can set up an [Icecast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icecast) server, that was developed for audio streams, but make it do a A/V stream instead.

It'd probably be more of a learning curve that simply putting on a web server and not worrying about it being real-time